# How to sort inserts on multiple tables on Oracle so that no FK constraint is broken

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to bring a DB from Oracle 12 to Oracle 11. I created all DDL for objects using SQL Explorer and after some minor adjustments it worked fine. But as I exported the data I got a bunch of inserts **sorted by table name** as shown bellow.

```
@C:\Users\RubensdoAmaralNeto\DBScripts\TABLE_A.sql
@C:\Users\RubensdoAmaralNeto\DBScripts\TABLE_B.sql
@C:\Users\RubensdoAmaralNeto\DBScripts\TABLE_C.sql
...
```

If I try to run it as is, it won't work because it breaks many FK constraints.

Is there a way to sort those inserts, other then manually doing the job? Maybe using SQL Explorer or SQLPlus. There are more then 150 tables that are related each other.

Comment: the quick and dirty answer - disable ALL of the constraints, do the INSERTS, then re-enable the constraints. HOPE that your data is 'clean' and no one else sneaks in whilst the constraints are disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive CTE that I think should list all your tables in the order that you should do the inserts. Assuming that all tables are in your current schema. Anything with a lvl of 0 can be run in any order.

```
with t (table_name, lvl) as (
    -- tables with no foreign keys on them
    select table_name, 0 as lvl from user_tables where table_name not in (select table_name from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'R')
    union all -- tables with foreign keys pointing to previous tables 
    select c.table_name as table_name, t.lvl+1 as lvl
    from t 
    join user_constraints r on r.table_name = t.table_name
    join user_constraints c 
      on c.constraint_type = 'R' 
      and r.constraint_name = c.r_constraint_name
    ) cycle table_name set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select table_name, lvl,
  '@C:\Users\RubensdoAmaralNeto\DBScripts\' || table_name || '.sql' as script
from t
order by lvl;
```

Just copy & paste the third column into a text file and save the script.